# Install Jupyter on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to install Jupiter on Ubuntu 14.04 onto my home directory.

I have my own local version of python 2.7 and pip that I would like it to run off. I tried using

```
pip install jupyter
```

but I get this error when it tries to install `simplegeneric`

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
        wb.build(autobuilding=True)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
        self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
        ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
        session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
        unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
        unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
        flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 484, in unzip_file
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
        self._RealGetContents()
    File "/users/dor/arqj/ahl/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
        raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install Jupyter in Ubuntu 14.04→16.10

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip python-dev
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

[for more information visit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847263/install-jupyter-for-python-2-7-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: any way to do so without using sudo, i do not have the privilege to use sudo

Comment: If you want without try http://winlandiano.github.io/informatik/2017/06/13/Installing-Jupyter-on-ipd-server-without-sudo-authority

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update

pip3 install jupyter
```